# Casting error adding Guid value to Dictionary<string, object> inside an IQueryable.Select() lambda expression selector:

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

The code fragment below uses the IQueryable.Select() method to perform generic property projections on a given query, according to a list of given property names.

The program works fine if all the properties are of type 'string', but it triggers the exception below when some property is of a different type, like 'Guid'.

***Expression of type 'System.Guid' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Object' of method 'Void Add(System.String, System.Object)***

How can I solve this problem?

```
public static IQueryable SelectProperties<T>(this IQueryable<T> baseQuery, String[] selectedProperties) where T : class 
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
    var addMethod = typeof(Dictionary<string, object>).GetMethod("Add");
    List<ElementInit> dicadds = new List<ElementInit>();
    foreach (var selectedProperty in selectedProperties)
    {
        var eKey = Expression.Constant(selectedProperty);
        var eValue = Expression.Property(parameter, selectedProperty);
        var eAdd = Expression.ElementInit(addMethod, eKey, eValue);
        dicadds.Add(eAdd);
    }
    var dicinit = Expression.ListInit(Expression.New(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>)), dicadds);
    var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, dynamic>>(dicinit, parameter);
    return baseQuery.Select(selector);
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the failing code calling SelectProperties as well.

Comment: The exception occurs inside the method, on the following line:
var eAdd = Expression.ElementInit(addMethod, eKey, eValue);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens for all value types. Value types are not objects, but C# is supposed to automatically box value types, but where you are building an expression yourself, you might be bypassing that.

The following change converts everything to object, thus boxing value types.

```
var eKey = Expression.Constant(selectedProperty);
var eValue = Expression.Property(parameter, selectedProperty);
Expression boxed = Expression.Convert(eValue, typeof(object));
var eAdd = Expression.ElementInit(addMethod, eKey, boxed);
dicadds.Add(eAdd);
```